# How to generate static initialization block with jcodeModel

Tags: jcodemodel

I need to generate something like this with jcodemodel

```
package com.example;

    public class Main {

    static int a;

    static {
        a = 5;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Google did not help. There is a class `JBlock` but there is nothing about initialization blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

need to call JDefinedClass.init() which returns JBlock